# Life on oceans above the sky

Tags: atmosphere, flora, ocean

> The **[Leidenfrost effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leidenfrost_effect)** is a physical phenomenon in which a liquid, in near contact with a mass significantly hotter than the liquid's boiling point, produces an insulating vapor layer keeping that liquid from boiling rapidly. Because of this 'repulsive force', a droplet hovers over the surface rather than making physical contact with it.

[image]
[Source](https://steemit.com/steemstem/@omstavan/the-leidenfrost-effect)

---

If this is to be applied on a planetary scale, one can imagine entire bodies of water floating over a hot, humid landscape.

What kind of life forms might evolve in a place where liquid water only forms above the ground?

Comment: There is a huge difference between a droplet and an ocean when you look at the interaction with a hot surface. Also your picture states that the droplet will end up evaporating.

Comment: One could imagine such a world exists. i think the premise is fine, it wouldn't work in reality, but neither does the Force and some people continue to watch those Star Wars movies. In order to ensure that people don't focus on how this cannot happen, please include a statement saying that you are not interested in having explained to you how basic Physics work. However, I don't think your actual question is a good fit. What do you expect people to base their answers on? How is this anything but just wild guessing, which is called "opinion based" in this SE and a reason to close the topic?

Comment: @Raditz_35, my point is that, even assuming an entire ocean could float above a steam cushion, it would be so hot that it would be a fish soup. If life could form at all, being separated by any form of minerals.

Comment: @L.Dutch I might be able to come up with a billion reasons why this wouldn't work in reality (starting with: it takes billions of years for any interesting lifeform to evolve, how do you keep this surface hot?), but the new Star Wars movie made like 200 million in a week, so who cares? Just imagine it's cold enough for whatever

Comment: This is an interesting idea, but you've effectively asked what forms evolution might take in a three dimensional non-gravitational environment, we could write books about that. Larry Niven did it already, two very good books that barely scratch the surface, this is almost the definition of _too-broad_.

Comment: @Ash, non gravitational? why?

Comment: @L.Dutch Buoyancy, in water everything floats right.

Comment: Just the question "what kind of life might evolve..." is far too broad for a WB Q&A format, even ignoring the impossibility of a planetary scale effect like you're asking for.

Comment: @StephenG I can think of feasible ideas for a planetary environment that conforms to this model, not ones that would support life mind you.